# Does not work adding of string after after a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I want to find ssh port and add this port script after string `### SSHPORT_TAG`.

My script:

```
PORTSSH=$( set | grep "\(SSH_CONNECTION\)" | sed -e "s/^SSH_CONNECTION='//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s/'//g" | grep "[0-9]*")
sed "s/.*SSHPORT_TAG.*/&\nSSHport=$PORTSSH/" rc.firewall
```

But it does not work. In debug i have:

```
++ grep '[0-9]*'
++ sed -e 's/'\''//g'
++ sed -e 's/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20//g'
++ sed -e 's/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20[0-9]*\x20//g'
++ sed -e 's/^SSH_CONNECTION='\''//g'
++ grep '\(SSH_CONNECTION\)'
++ set
+ PORTSSH='22
    PORTSSH=$( set | grep "\(SSH_CONNECTION\)" | sed -e "s/^SSH_CONNECTION=//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s///g" | grep "[0-9]*");'
+ sed -i '/SSHPORT_TAG/a SSHPORT=22
    PORTSSH=$( set | grep "\(SSH_CONNECTION\)" | sed -e "s/^SSH_CONNECTION=//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\x20//g" | sed -e "s///g" | grep "[0-9]*");' rc.firewall
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: extra characters after command
```

Why it does not work ? Xan you help me in this case ? Thanks.

Comment: Btw: I suggest to replace first line with: `PORTSSH=${SSH_CONNECTION##* }`

Comment: Add file `rc.firewall` and your desired output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer why it doesn't work the line which causes error is after the portion of code in the question, somthing like :

```
sed -i '/SSHPORT_TAG/a SSHPORT='"$PORTSSH"
```

But PORTSSH doesn't contain just 22 but 22 followed by newline and other shell expressions that sed doesn't understand.

To go in the same direction as @Cyrus in the comments, there's an important overhead to launch a sub-shell, 2 grep processes, 4 sed processes with pipes to process variable content.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

```
${parameter#pattern} # to remove smallest prefix which matches pattern
${parameter##pattern} # to remove longest prefix which matches pattern
${parameter%pattern} # to remove smallest suffix which matches pattern
${parameter%%pattern} # to remove longest suffix which matches pattern
${parameter/pat/repl} # to replace first match with repl
${parameter//pat/repl} # to replace all matches with repl
```

here the pattern follow the rules of glob pattern (* any string, ? any character).

Otherwise bash supports also regular expressions

For example

```
if [[ 127.0.0.1:22 =~ ([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*):([0-9]*) ]]; then 
    printf "<%s> " "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
fi
```